# Office apps not saving Background/Theme across restarts

Tags: themes, microsoft-outlook-2016, system-preferences

[*e.g.* Outlook 2016 16.0.4456.1003, 64 bit on Windows 10 Pro x64 v 1607]

Subject says it all - when I change the Office Background or Office Theme, and then restart Outlook/Excel/... it reverts to No Background/Colorful Theme.

Answer (score 6):

I had same problem. I solved it by checking my Office Account (example using Outlook: File > Office Account). There in the User Account Info there was a message saying there was a problem with my Microsoft Account and offered to fix it. I clicked on the Fix It message and it solved the problem.

Comment: Found this button and was prompted to re-enter my password, which I changed at the time it started doing this. Interestingly these credentials seem to operate separately to Skype for Business as I had already updated that.

Answer (score 2):

Ticking this option may help:

File > Options > General. "Always use these values regardless of sign in to Office.

[image]